# How to copy files or sql database tables from a linux machine to Adls gen2 using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to copy files or sql database tables from a linux machine to Adls gen2 using azure data factory. Kindly please help me with the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data sources in a physical or virtual network can be scanned using a self-hosted integration runtime (SHIR). but we can't install Integration Runtime (self-hosted) on Linux server it is currently only available on windows ([see here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717)).

To work around this, to transfer files to or from a storage account, you can use the command-line tool **`AzCopy`**.

***Syntax***

```
azcopy copy '<local-file-path>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-name>/<file-name><SAS-token>'
```

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10

Comment: Hi pratik. Thank for your response. In case of databases how can we handle this? extract into files then use AZcopy? or there any better way of doing this?